# Conditionally Render Image on Server in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I feel like I already know the answer to this, but just wanted to see if anyone had a solution for this.

I have a hero banner where I have one image I want to show on mobile, but there's another I want to show on desktop.

Usually I would just conditionally render it, but then I get that weird flicker where the image first loads something by default and then switches to the right one.

Is there another way to deal with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use CSS media queries. Or even better, an image with conditional srcset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use media queries to see if that would render on the server first and it seems to be doing what I want to be doing!

```
    <>
      <Image
        height={800}
        width={800}
        className="w-full max-lg:min-h-[515px] max-lg:scale-[1]  lg:hidden"
        src={heroMobile.src}
        alt="hero"
      />
      <Image
        height={1600}
        width={1600}
        className="hidden lg:flex"
        src={hero.src}
        alt="hero"
      />
    </>
```

But if anyone else has another solution please still share.

Edit: Sorry I had posted this before refreshing and saw there were answers.